# How to align pivot to the center of a hole

Tags: mesh

I've got a button model, that is supposed to be rotate around the pivot point in the center,

[image]

But how to set the pivot point to the exact center is a problem, the center should be further into the hollow area

I know this model is simple and if you create it from a cylinder the pivot is what I want, but I want to know if say I got model from other people and the pivot is not in the center, how can I align it to the center,thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Edit mode, '2' for edge select then ALT-click on the top edge round the inside of the hole and SHIFT-S > Cursor to Selected.
If you want it half way down the hole, go to Face mode, ALT-Click one of the edges inside the hole to select the ring of inner faces then SHIFT-S > Cursor to Selected again.

Comment: This is pretty nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to John Eason's answer: don't forget to set your pivot point accordingly `Numpad .` > `3D cursor`

You could also pivot around the object's origin: `Numpad .` > `Individual origin`
But then you also have to set the origin correctly: After setting the 3D cursor in `Edit mode`, you can set the object's origin to the 3D cursor when you're back in `Object mode` (right click > `Set origin` > `Origin to 3D cursor`).

Also helpful in this regard are constraints, e.g. a `Limit Rotation` constraint so you can only rotate the knob around it's z-axis. Also limiting the amount of rotation is possible with that constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to setup the limit rotation constraint, but not working, so I opened up another thread: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211673/trouble-with-local-space-limit-rotation